# SQL query, treat NULL as zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning SQL (using MySQL) and have a very simple question.  I have a table with salary and bonus information on employees, and I'd like to sum the two, but have MySQL return the value zero when at least one of the summands is `NULL`, instead of returning `NULL`.  What's the easiest way to do this?

```
mysql> SELECT SALARY, BONUS FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
+----------+---------+
| SALARY   | BONUS   |
+----------+---------+
| 30000.00 | 2000.00 |
|     NULL |    NULL |
| 40000.00 |    NULL |
| 20000.00 | 1000.00 |
|     NULL |    NULL |
|     NULL |    NULL |
+----------+---------+

mysql> SELECT SALARY + BONUS FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
+----------------+
| SALARY + BONUS |
+----------------+
|       32000.00 |
|           NULL |
|           NULL |
|       21000.00 |
|           NULL |
|           NULL |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). It accepts a number of arguments and returns the first one that is not null.

You can use `IFNULL` too (not to be confused with `ISNULL`). It behaves the same in this scenario, but `COALESCE` is more portable; it allows multiple arguments and returns the first not-null one. Also, other databases support it too, so that makes it slightly easier to migrate to another database if you would like to in the future.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SALARY, 0) + COALESCE(BONUS, 0)
FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
```

or

```
SELECT IFNULL(SALARY, 0) + IFNULL(BONUS, 0)
FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
```

Both of them are just a very convenient way to write:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN SALARY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SALARY END +
  CASE WHEN BONUS IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE BONUS END
FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
```

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IFNULL(SALARY, 0), IFNULL(BONUS, 0) FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;`

You should use `IFNULL` function for that.

**CORRECTED**

Comment: It seems this gives an error: `mysql> SELECT ISNULL(SALARY, 0), ISNULL(BONUS, 0) FROM EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL;
ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. `IFNULL` is correct.